# The definition of the product of 2 paths.

Tags: continuity, homotopy-theory

The definition of the product of 2 paths, according to Ralph H. Fox and Richard H. Crowell, is as follows:

> Consider any two paths $a$ and $b$ in $X$ which are such that the terminal point of $a$ coincides with the initial point of $b$, i.e., $a(||a||) = b(0)$. The product $a.b$ of the paths $a$ and $b$ is defined by the formula:
>   $$ (a.b)(t) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
> a(t) & { 0 \leq t \leq ||a||}, \\
> b(t - ||a||), & {||a|| \leq t \leq ||a|| + ||b||.}
> \end{array} \right. $$ 
>   It is obvious that this defines a continuous function.

**My questions are:**

1-Why we are sure that this defines a continuous function?

2- Is there an intuition behind this definition?

Could anyone help me answering these questions please?

Comment: Prove that left-hand and right-hand limits at $t=\|a\|$ are equal.

Comment: Why all the vertical bars?

Comment: Continuity follows from the pasting lemma, which says that a function which is continuous on two closed sets is continuous on their union.

Comment: @Randall: $\|a\|$ presumably denotes the 'length' of the path, $\|a\|\ge0$ and $a$ is defined on the interval $[0,\,\|a\|] $. An adventage of this setup is that path composition already becomes associative.

Comment: @Randall yes exactly vertical bars denote the length

Comment: @Berci thanks for clarification to Randall my intention.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I got for the left hand limit it equals $a(||a||)$ ..... but what about the right hand limit .....it is very confusing for me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  No thanks I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As both of them are continuous and coincide on their interection.

2) Yes, let me show you a picture I once drew for that:

[image]

This drawing actually shows loops (paths with same start and termianl point) but the intuition is the same. You walk through the red loop $a$ and then through the blue loop $b$ to get the purple loop. So the multiplication is the concatenation.