# Three equivalent assertions in pg.14 in Ralph H. Fox book of knot theory.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

The book says:

> Consider any two paths $a$ and $b$ in $X$ which are such that the terminal point of $a$ coincides with the initial point of $b$, i.e., $a(||a||) = b(0)$.It is obvious that the three assertions:
>
> (i)$a.b$ and $b.c$ are defined.
>
> (ii) $a.(b.c)$ is defined.
>
> (iii) $(a.b) . c$ is defined.
>
> are equivalent.

But I do not know how is this obvious, could anyone help me to prove them please?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I am sorry there is a typo I will correct it ..... thanks!

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot more sense. Basically all three are saying the endpoint of $a$ matches the start point of $b$, and the end point of $b$ matches the start point of $c$.

Comment: I think you may want to add some details to this. I'm assuming that $c$ is a third path with suitable endpoints, but you don't state this. What does $\|a\|$ mean? This is not standard notation. Paths are normally taken to parametrised by the interval $I=[0,1]$. What is $a.b$? Is this the standard concatenation of paths? What are equivlant paths? Is this meant to be path-homotopic? That is, homotopic by a homotopy that fixes the path endpoints.

Comment: @Tyrone For $c$ nothing is stated about it in the book. For $||a||$it means the terminal point of the path $a$ or the stopping time or the length of the path $a$. $a.b$ is the product of 2 paths and it is defined here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282411/the-definition-of-the-product-of-2-paths?noredirect=1#comment6751104_3282411 . until this point the book has not defined the equivalence of 2 paths, but the author explained it later. I think " Is this meant to be path-homotopic? That is, homotopic by a homotopy that fixes the path endpoints." this is exactly what the book said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i)\Rightarrow ii)$ If $a\cdot b$ is defined then $b(0)=a(\|a\|)$. If $b\cdot c$ is defined then $(b\cdot c)(0)=b(0)=(\|a\|)$. Hence $a\cdot(b\cdot c)$ is defined.

$ii)\Rightarrow iii)$ If $a\cdot (b\cdot c)$ is defined then $a(\|a\|)=(b\cdot c)(0)=b(0)$
so $a\cdot b$ is defined. Also this implies that $(a\cdot b)(\|a\cdot b\|)=b(\|b\|)=c(0)$, so that $(a\cdot b)\cdot c$ is defined.

$iii)\Rightarrow i)$ If $(a\cdot b)\cdot c$ is defined then clearly $a\cdot b$ is defined. Moreoreover $(a\cdot b)(\|a\cdot b\|)=b(\|b\|)=c(0)$, so $b\cdot c$ is defined.