# Product of any 2 p-based loops is again a p-based loop.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Knowing that the definition of product of 2 paths is as given here:

[The definition of the product of 2 paths.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282411/the-definition-of-the-product-of-2-paths?noredirect=1#comment6751104_3282411)

How can I show that: Product of any 2 p-based loops is again a p-based loop.

The book said that it is clear, but can anyone tell me a justification for this please?

**EDIT:**

A path in a topological space $X$ is then a continuous mapping $$a:[0, ||a||] \rightarrow X.$$
where the number $a$ is the stopping time and it is assumed that $||a|| \geq 0.$

A path whose initial and terminal points coincide is called a loop.

Comment: What have you tried, what is blocking you ?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of a p-based loop properly, and also the definition of the product of loops? I would suggest writing those definitions out carefully and including them in your definition. This may help both yourself and also us.

Comment: I have tried but I am confused about $||a||$ in the definition of the product of 2 paths, by what value I would substitute in case of a loop? @Max

Comment: I have tried but I am confused about $||a||$ in the definition of the product of 2 paths, by what value I would substitute in case of a loop? @Matt

Comment: It is just the sum of the two lengths

Comment: No I do not think so in case of p-based loop. @Max

Comment: This is what the definition in the given link says

Comment: I do not understand this point @Max

Comment: It appears as though what you don't understand here is the definition of the product of two paths. If you don't like the one at the above source, try googling it and seeing what you come up with. It should then be pretty clear what is meant by $||a||$.

Comment: And like I said, in this case please add your working definition of path, loop, and product of paths to the question. It should help us help you.

Comment: @Matt  what value I would substitute in case of a loop?

Comment: Ok @Matt I will edit my question

Comment: I'm not going to tell you that because (as you have already demonstrated) that won't help your understanding. Try looking in other sources, where it will be more clear what your definition should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed trivial:
If $a$ and $b$ are $p$-loops, that means
$$p=a(0)=a(\|a\|)=b(0)=b(\|b\|)$$
Thus, by the definition of product of paths, we will have $(ab)(0)=a(0)=p$ and $(ab)(\|ab\|)=(ab)(\|a\|+\|b\|)=b(\|b\|) =p$.